# Opening database managing handles

Tags: java

I am using berkeley database....

Generally at this type of database you open an environment which is a bunch of files to control locking and transactions etc and then you open your database in this environment...

The problem is that there are LOTS of databases to open....
The method to open a database is    `opendatabase()`
However opening and closing the database always is slow... The documentation says

> Opening a database is a relatively
>   expensive operation, and maintaining a
>   set of open databases will normally be
>   preferable to repeatedly opening and
>   closing the database for each new
>   query.

The problem is how to maintain that set ??????
A simple solution i thought was lazy loading

```
 private static Database db;
     public   CustomerDAO() {
            if (db == null) {
                try {
                    DatabaseConfig dbConfig = new DatabaseConfig();
                    dbConfig.setAllowCreate(true);
                    dbConfig.setType(DatabaseType.BTREE);
                    db = BDBEnvironment.DEFAULT.getEnvironment().openDatabase(null, "C:\\xxxx\\CUSTOMERS",
                            null, dbConfig);
```

But this has a problem with double check locking.. Right???
Another issue is that i want to have a default file name or a user specified one..  Of course it is easy to create a DatabaseManager but always double check lock issue would occur.
Any ideas how to maintain a set of database handles??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use basic Java synchronization techniques and a thread-safe data structure such as a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to store your DB handles. You should probably read [this book](http://jcip.net/) if you haven't already, as it covers a lot of what you'll need for this kind of issue.

Comment: thanks for the book :) However what  can i do now? ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe but handle creation? When should that happen?

Comment: Lazy loading would be fine as long as it's done in a thread safe manner. Alternatively, create a central initialization routine which opens all the databases you need ahead of time. The choice between them is dependent on your application's needs. You should also consider that while Oracle/Sleepycat say it's "expensive", BerkeleyDB is really fast and you should at least measure how long it takes to open all the databases in one shot before you consider any other approach. It may turn out to be quite acceptable for your needs to just open them all and be done with it.